# Oracle does not use transitive closure to add additional predicate

Tags: oracle, optimization, execution-plan, oracle-12c

Presented with a query like this:

```sql
select *
from a, b
where a.val = b.val
 and a.val = 1
```

Oracle optimizer can use transitive closure property and combine two predicates `a.val = b.val` and `a.val = 1` to deduce another: `b.val = 1`. It can be seen in Predicate Information of an execution plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |       |   600 |  3600 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                           |       |   600 |  3600 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| B     |    20 |    60 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | VAL_I |    20 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | A     |    30 |    90 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."VAL"="B"."VAL")
   3 - access("B"."VAL"=1)
   4 - filter("A"."VAL"=1)
```

However, on another environment (same Oracle version - 12.1.0.2) I cannot reproduce the same behavior:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |   360 |  2160 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |      |   360 |  2160 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |    30 |    90 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |  1000 |  3000 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."VAL"="B"."VAL")
   2 - filter("A"."VAL"=1)
```

Because of the missing predicate the index is not used. Reported cardinality is also incorrect.

Is there a way to control this behavior, possibly via an optimizer parameter?

Comment: Is the estimated number of rows correct for the other environment? But as both execution plans are identical in terms of the steps they do, I don't see why that would be a problem to begin with?

Comment: Estimated number of rows is incorrect in the second case. Since there is no predicate on the `B` table the plan reports that all 1000 rows will be fetched. Execution plans seem the same in terms of cost only for this simple example i devised to demonstrate the problem. In reality it causes full table scans on multi-million tables even though a fast index path could be used.

Comment: Well, if the plans do deviate in reality, you should show us an example where this is actually a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that parameter `_optimizer_filter_pushdown` was set to `false` which *also* affects transitive predicate generation, just like `_optimizer_generate_transitive_pred` that Balazs Papp suggested. After setting it to true the problem goes away:

```sql
alter session set "_optimizer_filter_pushdown"=true;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
create table a(val number);
create table b(val number);
explain plan for select * from a, b where a.val = b.val and a.val = 1;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 652036164

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |      |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."VAL"="B"."VAL")
   2 - filter("A"."VAL"=1)
   3 - filter("B"."VAL"=1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

And the parameter:

```
SQL> alter session set "_optimizer_generate_transitive_pred"=false;

Session altered.

SQL> explain plan for select * from a, b where a.val = b.val and a.val = 1;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 652036164

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |      |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."VAL"="B"."VAL")
   2 - filter("A"."VAL"=1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```